# Logical "and" in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

I'm looking into writing a GitHub Action that triggers if none of the regexes match.

An MWE would look like

```yaml
jobs:
  check_pr_title:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions-ecosystem/action-regex-match@v2
        id: feature-match
        with:
          text: ${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}
          regex: '^\[(feature|feat\.?)\] \#?([[:digit:]]+|\(([[:digit:]]+,?\s?)+\)):.+$'

      - uses: actions-ecosystem/action-regex-match@v2
        id: refactor-match
        with:
          text: ${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}
          regex: '^\[ref(actor)?\]( \#?([[:digit:]]+|\(([[:digit:]]+,?\s?)+\)):)?.+$'

      - uses: actions-ecosystem/action-regex-match@v2
        id: fix-match
        with:
          text: ${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}
          regex: '^\[(bug)?fix(up)?\] \#?([[:digit:]]+|\(([[:digit:]]+,?\s?)+\)):.+$'

      - name: Failure
        if: ${{ steps.fix-match.outputs.match == '' & steps.refactor-match.outputs.match == '' & ... }}
        run: exit 1
```

Which fails since & isn’t recognised.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, how it didn't work (e.g. error message) etc. Please don't just paste your code.

Comment: You want [`&&`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#operators).